# WKB to WKT JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, well-known-text, well-known-binary

Turns out json [isn't so good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64) at transporting binary data. But with HTML5, XHR2 is now capable [of transferring blobs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) cleanly. I'm looking to transfer binary geometry (to save bandwidth) and decode it on the client.

To no avail, I've scoured the web for a javascript-based [WKB (Well-known Binary)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary) to [WKT (Well-known Text)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) function. Before I re-invent the wheel -- is anyone aware of any open-source solutions?

Comment: Btw, you should not use blobs but arraybuffer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like a new and better supported JS WKB parsing library has since appeared.

https://github.com/cschwarz/wkx

I've been able to use it to convert WKB directly from postgres into JS objects that can be mapped in the browser.  You'll need to include https://github.com/cschwarz/wkx/blob/master/dist/wkx.js in your webpage for this to work.

```
// Required imports (works in browser, too)
var wkx = require('wkx');
var buffer = require('buffer');

// Sample data to convert
var wkbLonlat = '010100000072675909D36C52C0E151BB43B05E4440';

// Split WKB into array of integers (necessary to turn it into buffer)
var hexAry = wkbLonlat.match(/.{2}/g);
var intAry = [];
for (var i in hexAry) {
  intAry.push(parseInt(hexAry[i], 16));
}

// Generate the buffer
var buf = new buffer.Buffer(intAry);

// Parse buffer into geometric object
var geom = wkx.Geometry.parse(buf);

// Should log '-73.700380647'
console.log(geom.x)

// Should log '40.739754168'
console.log(geom.y)
```

Comment: Hey, OP here. Asked this 1.5 years ago. Awesome!

Answer (score 7):

The only solution pure javascript solution I've found so far (and I did not try) is https://github.com/thejefflarson/wkb.js.
It's only an incomplete WKB parser (it converts WKB to a js object you can transform to WKT)

An alternative way to wkb on javascript side can be the experimental twkb (not a standard at the moment)
http://blog.jordogskog.no/2013/05/05/mapservice-from-websocket-with-twkb/ but it requires to play with a custom PostGIS build (so really not for beginners)

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility might be to use [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/) instead of plain GeoJSON:

> **TopoJSON** is an extension of GeoJSON that encodes topology. Rather than
>   representing geometries discretely, geometries in TopoJSON files are
>   stitched together from shared line segments called *arcs*. TopoJSON
>   eliminates redundancy, offering much more compact representations of
>   geometry than with GeoJSON; typical TopoJSON files are 80% smaller
>   than their GeoJSON equivalents.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by ThomasG77 I have been playing with binary data in this "twkb" format.

you can see it in action [here](http://tinyurl.com/clj26cn) (a websocket example)

or [here](http://tinyurl.com/d6fyasm), a php implementation.

If you want to study the parsing check the file twkb.js. It is a little cleaner in the twkb_node example I think.

In [this](http://blog.jordogskog.no/2013/04/09/tiny-wkb/) blog post you can find link to the source code of the PostGIS part and some description of the format.

I have done some reworking since and will soon put a new description on github. I have a believe in twkb, but it needs more brains to get good.

You can of course also parse wkb but you will gain no bandwidth compared to gzipped geojson. I was surprised how small that did get. See the second link and check the sizes of the geojson vs twkb. WKB is about 2-6 times bigger than twkb.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not about wkb to wkt function.

I'd say you shouldn't use conversion from wkt to wkb just to save bandwith - gzipping wkt (or other format you have there) on the server should be more than enough (and most probably - more efficient) and browsers can do unzipping on the fly and out of the box.

Look also at [browser support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) for XHTMLRequest2, as it's not supported in some older, yet still used browsers.

Answer (score 0):

GeoScript has a Javascript API that reads and writes WKT and WKB. The methods are part of geom.io.

Comment: FIY only in a shell environment with java dependencies (cf pom.xml at http://github.com/tschaub/geoscript-js/) not in the browser